# Why do I get an error message using the lqmm function in R?

Tags: r

I'm using lqmm function in R.  Here is the code

```
m1.5=lqmm(fixed=ltpa~lqmd, random=~1+lqmd, tau=.975, data=data, 
          control=lqmmControl(LP_max_iter=100000), 
          na.action=na.omit)
```

I receive an error message: Error in

> sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain, trim = trim), ...) :    invalid
> type of argument[1]: 'language'

I'm tried looking up in google and R documentation, but I could not find the error.

Comment: Using a data object with a name of ‘data’ is a prescription for confusion.